# Can this technique for creating a container of heterogenous functors be salvaged?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

This [blog post](http://wisol.ch/w/articles/2015-03-08-callbacks-in-cpp11/) describes a technique for creating a container of heterogeneous pointers. The basic trick is to create a trivial base class (i.e. no explicit function declarations, no data members, nothing) and a templated derived class for storing `std::function<>` objects with arbitrary signatures, then make the container hold `unique_ptr`s to objects of the base class. The code is also [available on GitHub.](https://github.com/wisoltech/cpp11-callbacks/blob/master/callback4.cc)

I don't think this code can be made robust; `std::function<>` can be created from a lambda, which might include a capture, which might include a by-value copy of a nontrivial object whose destructor must be called. When the `Func_t` type is deleted by `unique_ptr` upon removal from the map, only its (trivial) destructor will be called, so the `std::function<>` objects never get properly deleted.

I've replaced the use-case code from the example on GitHub with a "non-trivial type" that is then captured by value inside a lambda and added to the container. In the code below, the parts copied from the example are noted in comments; everything else is mine. There's probably a simpler demonstration of the problem, but I'm struggling a bit to even get a valid compile out of this thing.

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <typeindex>
#include <iostream>

// COPIED FROM https://plus.google.com/+WisolCh/posts/eDZMGb7PN6T
namespace {

  // The base type that is stored in the collection.
  struct Func_t {};
  // The map that stores the callbacks.
  using callbacks_t = std::map<std::type_index, std::unique_ptr<Func_t>>;
  callbacks_t callbacks;

  // The derived type that represents a callback.
  template<typename ...A>
    struct Cb_t : public Func_t {
      using cb = std::function<void(A...)>;
      cb callback;
      Cb_t(cb p_callback) : callback(p_callback) {}
    };

  // Wrapper function to call the callback stored at the given index with the
  // passed argument.
  template<typename ...A>
    void call(std::type_index index, A&& ... args)
    {
      using func_t = Cb_t<A...>;
      using cb_t = std::function<void(A...)>;
      const Func_t& base = *callbacks[index];
      const cb_t& fun = static_cast<const func_t&>(base).callback;
      fun(std::forward<A>(args)...);
    }

} // end anonymous namespace

// END COPIED CODE

class NontrivialType
{
  public:
    NontrivialType(void)
    {
      std::cout << "NontrivialType{void}" << std::endl;
    }

    NontrivialType(const NontrivialType&)
    {
      std::cout << "NontrivialType{const NontrivialType&}" << std::endl;
    }

    NontrivialType(NontrivialType&&)
    {
      std::cout << "NontrivialType{NontrivialType&&}" << std::endl;
    }


    ~NontrivialType(void)
    {
      std::cout << "Calling the destructor for a NontrivialType!" << std::endl;
    }

    void printSomething(void) const
    {
      std::cout << "Calling NontrivialType::printSomething()!" << std::endl;
    }
};

// COPIED WITH MODIFICATIONS
int main()
{
  // Define our functions.
  using func1 = Cb_t<>;

  NontrivialType nt;
  std::unique_ptr<func1> f1 = std::make_unique<func1>(
      [nt](void)
      {
        nt.printSomething();
      }
  );

  // Add to the map.
  std::type_index index1(typeid(f1));
  callbacks.insert(callbacks_t::value_type(index1, std::move(f1)));

  // Call the callbacks.
  call(index1);

  return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output (using G++ 5.1 with no optimization):

```
NontrivialType{void}
NontrivialType{const NontrivialType&}
NontrivialType{NontrivialType&&}
NontrivialType{NontrivialType&&}
NontrivialType{const NontrivialType&}
Calling the destructor for a NontrivialType!
Calling the destructor for a NontrivialType!
Calling the destructor for a NontrivialType!
Calling NontrivialType::printSomething()!
Calling the destructor for a NontrivialType!
```

I count five constructor calls and four destructor calls. I *think* that indicates that my analysis is correct--the container cannot properly destroy the instance it owns.

**Is this approach salvageable?** When I add a virtual `=default` destructor to `Func_t`, I see a matching number of ctor/dtor calls:

```
NontrivialType{void}
NontrivialType{const NontrivialType&}
NontrivialType{NontrivialType&&}
NontrivialType{NontrivialType&&}
NontrivialType{const NontrivialType&}
Calling the destructor for a NontrivialType!
Calling the destructor for a NontrivialType!
Calling the destructor for a NontrivialType!
Calling NontrivialType::printSomething()!
Calling the destructor for a NontrivialType!
Calling the destructor for a NontrivialType!
```

... so I *think* this change might be sufficient. Is it?

(Note: the correctness--or lack thereof--of this approach is *independent* of whether the idea of a container of heterogeneous functions is a good idea. In a few very specific cases, there may be some merit, for instance, when designing an interpreter; e.g., a Python class may be thought of as just such a container of heterogeneous functions plus a container of heterogeneous data types. But in general, my decision to ask this question does **not** indicate that I think this is likely to be a good idea in very many cases.)

Comment: Yes, you (obviously) need a virtual destructor. But this is basically a buggy and unsafe version of `boost::any`.

Comment: This is an extremely roundabout way to emulate a `void*`, with all its inherent safety.

Comment: @T.C. Do you mean that the `Func_t` type here is essentially playing the same role as `boost::any`? Or that `boost::any` itself can be used like a generic function type somehow?

Comment: @KyleStrand I mean that you can just use a `map<..., boost::any>` over this stuff and there would be zero loss (and actually significant gains in safety, and of course, ease of implementation). Despite the name, `Func_t` is not "a generic function type"; it doesn't do, well, *anything*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is basically someone trying to implement type erasure and getting it horribly wrong.

Yes, you need a virtual destructor. The dynamic type of the thing being deleted is *obviously* not `Func_t`, so it's plainly UB if the destructor isn't virtual.

The whole design is completely broken, anyway.

The point of type erasure is that you have a bunch of different types that share a common characteristic (e.g. "can be called with an `int` and get a `double` back"), and you want to make them into a single type that has that characteristic (e.g., `std::function<double(int)>`). By its nature, type erasure is a one-way street: once you have erased the type, you can't get it back without knowing what it is.

What does erasing something down to an empty class mean? Nothing, other than "it's a thing". It's a `std::add_pointer_t<std::common_type_t<std::enable_if_t<true>, std::void_t<int>>>` (more commonly known as `void*`), obfuscated in template clothing.

There are plenty of other problems with the design. Because the type was erased into nothingness, it had to recover the original type in order to do anything useful with it. But you can't recover the original type without knowing what it is, so it ends up using the type of arguments passed to `Call` to infer the type of the thing stored in the map. That is ridiculously error-prone, because `A...`, which represents the types and value categories of the arguments passed to `Call`, is highly unlikely to match exactly the parameter types of `std::function`'s template argument. For instance, if you have a `std::function<void(int)>` stored in there, and you tried to call it with a `int x = 0; Call(/* ... */ , x);`, it's undefined behavior. Go figure.

To make it worse, any mismatch is hidden behind a `static_cast` that causes undefined behavior, making it harder to find and fix. There's also the curious design that requires the user to pass a `type_index`, when you "know" what the type is anyway, but it's just a sideshow when compared to all the other problems with this code.

Comment: I think it's trying to achieve zero memory cost for events with no subscribers, much the same as the .NET `System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList` collection does.  The varying types come not from multicasting a single event, but from exposing a large number of events.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think you mean "zero non code memory cost", as the existence of the types themselves has a memory cost in a .net situation where they are reflectable, no?  And there must be some way to identify the event (be it a type, or a string, or something), which is going to have a memory cost...  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Yakk: code memory is O(1) in the number of instances created, so ignored for scaling purposes.  The idea is for some reusable library widget to expose dozens or even hundreds of extension points (event sources), most of which will not be used by any given library client.  And to have thousands of widgets active.  In that case, memory proportional to both (number of events defined) and (number of widget instances) becomes problematic, it's much better if you can get to (number of events handled) times (number of widget instances) instead, and the additive terms for (events defined) is ok.

Comment: @benvoigt so, (number of types)*(number of events) code + (number of instances) state.  When you register an event, it stores (instance) and (event type).  The object broadcasts (instance) (event type) with a package of arguments, which is usually ignored, but if not, is sent to registered events.  To do this right in C++, you'd want to couple the erasure of the arguments with the erasure of the receiver, with the same class handling both packing and unpacking of arguments I think?

Comment: @BenVoigt Interesting--the person who pointed me to that blog article and asked me whether I thought it was an okay approach said (when I asked why he thought a dynamically sized container of heterogeneous functions would be useful) something about Microsoft implementing such a thing for their "event table". I thought he meant something having to do with the operating system, but maybe he's thinking of the .NET thing you mention? Which would be somewhat odd, because he's typically very critical of .NET...

Comment: @KyleStrand: Well, MFC also had message maps, in addition to virtual member functions.  Virtual members (which Java also uses) have cost only per-type and not per-instance.... and message maps are even lower cost, charging each type only for the number of handled messages, not all messages known to the base class.  But the .NET `EventHandlerList` used in WinForms is closer kin to the code under discussion here.

Comment: @BenVoigt My suspicion, then, is that he's referring to a specific use of MFC message maps inside some OS code (or something like that). In any case, he has (fortunately) decided not to pursue this heterogenous-function-container idea.

Comment: @KyleStrand: MFC isn't used in OS code, it's an application framework.  Anyway, your coworker decided to do the simpler thing.  If profiling later shows that event callback pointers are a significant memory hog, that's the time to worry about packing them.